# Zariski tangent space and open Zariski subsets.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X = \text{Spec}(k[X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}] / I)$ be an affine scheme. I have the two following questions:

1. Suppose $Y \subset X$ is a locally closed subscheme of $X$ such that $Y$ is reduced. If we have the equality of Zariski tangent spaces $T_{y}Y = T_{y}X$ for all $y \in Y$, then $Y$ is open in $X$.
2. Analogous to the first question, but replacing the condition $T_{y}Y = T_{y}X$ with the condition $T_{y}Y = T_{y}X_{red}$ for all $y \in Y$, where $X_{red}$ is the reduced subscheme of $X$.

I think that the proof of the first one is straightforward using the typical argument of dimension of $X$ as one do in the context of differentiable manifolds. Nevertheless I am not sure about how to proceed in the second case, is just because $X_{red}$ and $X$ have the same underlying topological space?

Comment: for (1): If $dim(Y) < dim(X)$ and $dim(T_y(Y))=dim(T_y(X))$ it follows $y$ is singular, but the set of singular points in $Y$ is a strict closed subset of $Y$, hence this cannot happen. Hence if $Z \subsetneq X$ is a strict closed subscheme with $Y:=U \cap Z$ with $U$ open, there has to be an $y\in Y$ with $T_y(Y) \subsetneq T_y(X)$.

Comment: ...hence (1) cannot hold if $Z \subsetneq X$.

Comment: Understood. Thanks! @hm2020